# MongoDB update array elements in nested array in aggregation pipeline

Tags: mongodb

I need to query a document and add some information from different collection into it to complete the query. Unfortunately the object I need to update is in an array which is nested in another array, so I have not found any clever way how to do that.

Example of document which needs to be updated:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
   "OuterArray": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "InnerArray": [
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 1,
          "Coefficient": 25
        },
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 2,
          "Coefficient": 25
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "InnerArray": [
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 3,
          "Coefficient": 25
        },
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 4,
          "Coefficient": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Documents in Economic center collection:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
  "Code": "One"
},
{
  "_id": 2,
  "Code": "Two"
},
{
  "_id": 3,
  "Code": "Three"
},
{
  "_id": 4,
  "Code": "Four"
}
```

I have created an aggregation pipeline, with lookup into another collection, but I cannot figure out how to put the additional information into the right place.

Expected outcome at the end of aggregation pipe:

```
{
  "_id": 1,
   "OuterArray": [
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "InnerArray": [
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 1,
          "Code":"One",
          "Coefficient": 25
        },
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 2,
      "Code": "Two",
          "Coefficient": 25
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Number": 1,
      "InnerArray": [
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 3,
      "Code": "Three",
          "Coefficient": 25
        },
        {
          "EconomicCenterId": 4,
          "Code": "Four"
          "Coefficient": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any help appreciated. Thank you.
MongoDB version is 4.0

Comment: It is recommended to upgrade to MongoDb v4.2+, so that you can use [$merge](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/) to update back to the collection.

Comment: Your OuterArray has `"Number": 1` for both entries. Is that correct?

Comment: @aneroid It can be the same, this parameter is independent, it is not some kind of identificator.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, here is my version of how I would do this.

It's slightly more complicated then the naive approach as I allow multiple documents to be fed into the input.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      //filter out any # of documents
      
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      source: [
        {
          $match: {}
        }
      ],
      codes: [
        {
          $limit: 1
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "economic_center",
            pipeline: [],
            as: "codes"
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            codes: 1
          }
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$codes"
        },
        {
          $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$codes"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        source: {
          $map: {
            input: "$source",
            as: "source",
            in: {
              "$mergeObjects": [
                "$$source",
                {
                  OuterArray: {
                    $map: {
                      input: "$$source.OuterArray",
                      as: "outer",
                      in: {
                        $mergeObjects: [
                          "$$outer",
                          {
                            InnerArray: {
                              $map: {
                                input: "$$outer.InnerArray",
                                as: "inner",
                                in: {
                                  "$mergeObjects": [
                                    "$$inner",
                                    {
                                      Code: {
                                        $getField: {
                                          field: "Code",
                                          input: {
                                            $arrayElemAt: [
                                              {
                                                $filter: {
                                                  input: "$codes",
                                                  as: "code",
                                                  cond: {
                                                    $eq: [
                                                      "$$code._id",
                                                      "$$inner.EconomicCenterId"
                                                    ]
                                                  }
                                                }
                                              },
                                              0
                                            ]
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                    }
                                  ]
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$source"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$source"
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/svfJMGnZQ4Y)